# Windows Firewall has blocked some features of IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: security, intellij-idea, windows-firewall, windows-security, intellij-idea-2016

I installed **IntelliJ IDEA 2016.3 Community Edition** and I created a simple Java class containing a `main` method that just prints a message. When I run that "program", the following window appears:

[image: Windows Security Alert]

> Windows Firewall has blocked some features of this program
>
> > Window Firewall has blocked some features of IntelliJ IDEA on all public and private networks.

If I go to **File** > **Settings...** > **Appeareance & Behavior** > **System Settings** > **Usage Statistics** > **Allow sending usage statistics to JetBrains s.r.o** is **unchecked**.

[image: Do not allow sending usage statistics to JetBrains]

If I go to `C:\Users\myusername\.IdeaIC2016.3\system\log`:

- `build-log\build.log` - nothing seems to be suspicious
- `idea.log` - the only interesting lines are:

  - at the first run, when the Windows Security Alert window appeared, there are 5 blocks that look like this (not identical):

    ```
    2016-12-01 09:42:53,814 [ 662361]   INFO - il.indexing.FileBasedIndexImpl - Rebuild requested for index org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinMetadataVersionIndex 
    java.lang.Throwable
        at com.intellij.util.indexing.FileBasedIndex.requestRebuild(FileBasedIndex.java:72)
        at org.jetbrains.kotlin.idea.versions.KotlinUpdatePluginComponent.initComponent(KotlinUpdatePluginComponent.kt:62)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl$ComponentConfigComponentAdapter.getComponentInstance(ComponentManagerImpl.java:501)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.createComponents(ComponentManagerImpl.java:125)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$createComponents$8(ApplicationImpl.java:441)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$3.run(CoreProgressManager.java:179)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:568)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:519)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:54)
        at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:164)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.createComponents(ApplicationImpl.java:448)
        at com.intellij.openapi.components.impl.ComponentManagerImpl.init(ComponentManagerImpl.java:109)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:400)
        at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.load(ApplicationImpl.java:386)
        at com.intellij.idea.IdeaApplication.run(IdeaApplication.java:190)
        at com.intellij.idea.MainImpl$1.lambda$null$0(MainImpl.java:47)
        at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:311)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:756)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(EventQueue.java:97)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:709)
        at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:703)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:76)
        at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:726)
        at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:363)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
        at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
    ```
  - after closing the Windows Security Alert window and running again:

    ```
    java.io.IOException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketDispatcher.read(SocketDispatcher.java:43)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.readIntoNativeBuffer(IOUtil.java:223)
        at sun.nio.ch.IOUtil.read(IOUtil.java:192)
        at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.read(SocketChannelImpl.java:380)
        at io.netty.buffer.PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.setBytes(PooledUnsafeDirectByteBuf.java:288)
        at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBuf.writeBytes(AbstractByteBuf.java:1100)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioSocketChannel.doReadBytes(NioSocketChannel.java:367)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:118)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:631)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:560)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:474)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:446)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:873)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    ```

What is IntelliJ IDEA trying to do?

And how can I prevent the cause for going to that Window Security Alert window?

**Edit**:
It also happens in IntelliJ IDEA 2017.1.

Comment: Have you tried monitoring the network to see what exactly it is IntelliJ is trying to do? What type of data is it attempting to send, and where is it sending it to? You can use e.g. [fidler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) to do this.

Comment: @Kjartan , no, I didn't. I can't install that software on this machine, but I will try to reproduce the problem on another machine and to try Fiddler. Thank you.